# Arc length of $x^3 \sqrt{9-x}$ on $[0,9]$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, radicals, closed-form, arc-length

This is supposed to be part of a student's Calc 2 homework; however, this seems to be an extremely difficult integration, and I couldn't figure it out.

Find the arc length of $x^3 \sqrt{9-x}$ on the interval $[0,9]$.

Progress so far:

The arc length L is given by:

$$L = \int_a^b{\sqrt{1 + {\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)}^2} \,\mathrm{d}x}$$

So we can find:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{(54-7x)x^2}{2\sqrt{9-x}}$$

And eventually we wind up with this mess:

$$\int_0^9{\sqrt{1 + \frac{(54-7x)^2 x^4}{4(9-x)}} \,\mathrm{d}x}$$

Which can be expanded out to:

$$\int_0^9{\sqrt{\frac{49x^6 - 756 x^5 + 2916 x^4 - 4x + 36}{36 - 4x}} \,\mathrm{d}x}$$

The sextic polynomial in the numerator seems to be irreducible.  However, it's possible to use polynomial long division on this beast, but it's unclear how that will help.  For posterity after dividing the integrand is:

$$-\frac1{4}\left( 49 x^5 - 315 x^4 + 81 x^3 + 729 x^2 + 6561 x + 59045 - \frac{531441}{9-x}\right)$$

Numerically, the answer is:

$$L = 1041.550819604016\ldots$$

Does this arc have a closed form solution for its length?

How, in general, are problems like these handled?

Comment: For clarity, I am not the student, this was asked on a homework help Discord I frequent, and I found myself completely unable to approach it.

Comment: $x$ is unbounded in the negatives.

Comment: Sorry, you are of course correct, this question was specified from [0, 9]

Comment: The question seems pathologically difficult. Was it faithfully copied ?

Comment: Yes, I double checked with the student, the original problem set can be found here: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/255350452391116800/563445204577681439/Screenshot_20190404-141329.png

Comment: Do you think $X^3$ isn't a typo of $x^3$, and it's actually a tricky question designed to be stupid?

Comment: A little sadistic IMO. I investigated the typo $x\sqrt[3]{9-x}$, without success.

Answer (score 1):

The form you have is likely the most "closed" you will find. Arc length integrals are generally difficult because of the square root and dot product involved, and only a few can be expressed "nicely," which is why there are so few arc length exercises in textbooks. In practice, a numerical solution can be found to arbitrary precision, so we're not too concerned with a closed form.

Comment: I agree with your supposition, but is there a way of reducing this expression into a form for which it can be proven that there is no closed form using elementary functions?

Comment: There is no general closed form solution to a polynomial of degree greater than or equal to 5, so the radicand is (likely) irreducible, as you said. It's therefore highly unlikely that the radical can be reduced and the antiderivative computed in closed form. It's possible, however, that you can express the integral in terms of special functions. As far as proof is concerned, I'm coming up empty.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity it's true that this is a *hard* problem for Calc 2, perhaps a numerical approximation was requested or a typo was made?

Comment: I thought that might have been the case, either a typo or something on the part of the student, so he provided me with the original questions: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/255350452391116800/563445204577681439/Screenshot_20190404-141329.png